# Mystery rodent in Winnipeg

Tags: species-identification, mammals, rodents

I spotted this rodent in Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada on September 6, 2020.

It is about 10 inches long.

[image]

What is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a **Franklin's Ground Squirrel**
[image]

Winnipeg is part of its range:

[image]

Have a look at a gallery of such photos here: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/179937-Poliocitellus-franklinii/browse_photos